# EF CF: many-to-many relation with additional info

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

We have legacy database and we map the new objects and props to the old tables and columns. So far so good. We have many-to-many relation which was mapped successfully. The intermediate table contains additional data. When we try to map the intermediate table to an object we get exception that the mapping is already defined. If we remove mapping from any side of the relation we get error that table is missing (ofc, we expect just that). I can do that easily with NHibernate and I am starting to think that EF is missing really really many features. So, please, tell me I am wrong and we can do that with EF.

Best regards

EDIT: here is a dummy sample which fails.

```
class User
{
  public ICollection<User> Followers{get;set;}
}

class UserRelation
{
  public User User{get;set;}
  public User Follower{get;set;}
  public DateTime CreatedOn{get;set;}
}
```

---

**user mapping**

```
modelBuilder
     .Entity<User>()
     .HasMany<User>(user => user.Followers)
     .WithMany()
     .Map(m =>m.MapLeftKey("user_id").MapRightKey("follower_id")
     .ToTable("user_follower"));
```

**user relation mapping**

```
modelBuilder
     .Entity<UserRelation>()
     .ToTable("user_follower");

modelBuilder
     .Entity<UserRelation>()
     .HasOptional<User>(f => f.User)
     .WithRequired().Map(m => m.MapKey("user_id"));

modelBuilder
     .Entity<UserRelation>()
     .HasOptional<User>(f => f.Follower)
     .WithRequired().Map(m => m.MapKey("follower_id"));

modelBuilder
     .Entity<UserRelation>()
     .Property(entity => entity.CreatedOn)
     .HasColumnName("created_on");
```

**Exception**

Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 
(67,6) : error 0019: The EntitySet 'UserUser' with schema 'dbo' and table 'user_follower' was already defined. Each EntitySet must refer to a unique schema and table.

Edit2: Here is another example of this model: http://learnentityframework.com/LearnEntityFramework/tutorials/many-to-many-relationships-in-the-entity-data-model/

Comment: I use EF for several many-to-many relationships quite successfully, perhaps if you show us some example of where your troubles are, we could help

Comment: Yes, I realized that and the sample is up

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Direct many-to-many mapping is available only if junction table contains just foreign keys. If you want to expose other properties in junction table you must map it to separate entity and mapt two one-to-many relations from former entities used in many-to-many.

I'm actually not able to write you the code because I don't understand your example.

Try only (don't map Many-to-many in User):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UserRelation>
    .HasRequired(r => r.User)
    .WithMany(u => u.Followers);

modelBuilder.Entity<UserRelation>
    .HasRequired(r => r.Follower)
    .WithMany();
```

Comment: One user can have many users. The many-to-many relation is not from 2 tables and junction table but 1 table and junction table. The separate Entity is UserRelation.

Comment: 10x, Imagine that User class is UserNew. When I remove the map in UserNew it tells me that UserNew_id does not exist. :|

Comment: Actually your map is working. Thanks. Can you explain why I had to remove the User map. In Nhibernate I do map both sides when I want bidirectional mapping.

Answer (score 1):

EF maps many-to-many relationships as properties of the related objects.

So, let's say you have `Cars` and `Drivers` that are related m-to-n. In your EF model, you will see that each `Car` object has a `Drivers` collection as a property, and each `Driver` object has a `Cars` collection as a property.

That is how m-to-n relationships are modeled in EF.

Comment: I know hot to create relations. I am not asking about that.

Comment: You may know how to create them, but I doubt you understand how they work, since you attempted to model the junction table.

Comment: 10x Brian but I think you are going to wrong direction. I updated the question with details about how I try to map the model.